# RHEL 6 KVM NIC configuration with bonding + vlan + bridge

Tags: networking, redhat, kvm-virtualization, rhel6

We are having trouble with our bonded NICs + vlan + bridged network configuration.  We have a blade server running RHEL6, and are trying to set up the networking for KVM virtualisation.

The blade server has 2 NICs (p2p1 and p2p2) which connect to the internal blade chassis 10 Gb switches.  We want to bond the 2 blade NICs and setup

1. default vlan (vlan 1) for our production network (172.16.x.x) assigned via DHCP, and
2. vlan 3 on our storage network (192.168.10.x) statically assigned.

There is an added complication that the KVM guests need to connect to our production network, and so we also need a bridge on the production network.

Setting up the bonding (as described [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces-chan.html)) together with vlan 3 (as described [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_802.1q-vlan-tagging.html)) seems fine.  We used the following configuration files

```
DEVICE=”p2p1”
BOOTPROTO=”none”
HWADDR=[Removed]
NM_CONTROLLED=”no”
ONBOOT=”yes”
TYPE=”Ethernet”
UUID=[Removed]
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no

DEVICE=”p2p2”
BOOTPROTO=”none”
HWADDR=[Removed]
NM_CONTROLLED=”no”
ONBOOT=”yes”
TYPE=”Ethernet”
UUID=[Removed]
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
USERCTL=no

DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCTL=no

DEVICE=bond0.3
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.10.22
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
VLAN=yes
```

The problem comes when we try to set up a bridged network connection for the default vlan (vlan 1).  For example we might try modifying bond0 and adding br0 as described [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/sect-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-Network_Configuration-Network_Configuration-Bridged_networking_with_libvirt.html).

```
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCTL=no
BRIDGE=br0

DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
```

However, br0 never obtains an IP over DHCP.  We know it's not a DHCP issues since DHCP works fine if we set it up directly on bond0, but that's not a bridge interface so the VMs can't use it.

How should we configure the interfaces for both vlan 3 (storage) and default vlan for KVM guests and administration?

Comment: Can you post the versions in use? Kernel, RHEL version, kvm/qemu/libvirt, what hardware is in use (`lspci`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An incompatibility between Cisco Rapid Spanning Tree and our blade centre switches led to our network engineers changing the design, so the question no longer applies.  However, I found the following discussions informative and they may help others in future.

- Similar setup, which was eventually confirmed as working [here](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/print.php?form=1&topic_id=36568&forum=58&order=ASC&start=0).
- A known issue with ARP with bridges on bonded interfaces [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO_BONDING).

Comment: The scheme you describe should work, but if you mentioned the versions, as requested, it would be possible to point you to the culprit.